# Keras ImageDataGenerator validation_split does not split validation data as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to learn about Computer Vision in Machine Learning with Tensorflow and Keras

I have a directory that contains 4185 images I got from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/smaranjitghose/corn-or-maize-leaf-disease-dataset
(I intentionally removed 3 images)

I have this code containing `listdir()` to check if it's true:

```py
import os
folders = os.listdir('/tmp/datasets/data')
print(f'folders: {folders}')

total_images = 0
for f in folders:
  total_images += len(os.listdir(f'/tmp/datasets/data/{f}'))

print(f'Total Images found: {total_images}')
```

The following is the output:

```
folders: ['Blight', 'Common_Rust', 'Gray_Leaf_Spot', 'Healthy']
Total Images found: 4185
```

I would like to split it into 80% train set and 20% validation set with Keras' ImageDataGenerator

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    width_shift_range = 0.05,
    height_shift_range = 0.05,
    rotation_range = 45,
    shear_range = 0.1,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    vertical_flip = True,
    validation_split = 0.2,
)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    validation_split = 0.2
)

train_images = datagen.flow_from_directory('/tmp/datasets/data',
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=42,
    subset='training',
    class_mode='categorical'
)

val_images = val_datagen.flow_from_directory('/tmp/datasets/data',
    target_size=(150,150), 
    batch_size=32, 
    seed=42,
    subset='validation', 
    class_mode='categorical'
)
```

The following is the output logged by `flow_from_directory()`:

```
Found 3350 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 835 images belonging to 4 classes.
```

The split done is not the expected `3348 | 837 (0.2 * 4185 = 837)`, did I miss something? or did I misinterpreted the parameter `validation_split`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is split for **each** folder (class) and **not** on the entire dataset. Check the source code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/3e380065d4afc7347aaee8d89325a16b22158438/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L247) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/3e380065d4afc7347aaee8d89325a16b22158438/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py#L199) to understand more. Here is an example of what `flow_from_directory` is doing internally:

```
import os

folders = os.listdir('/content/data')
print(f'folders: {folders}')

total_images = 0
names = []
paths = [] 
white_list_formats = ('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'ppm', 'tif', 'tiff')
for f in folders:
  paths.append(os.listdir(f'/content/data/{f}'))
  for d in os.listdir(f'/content/data/{f}'):
    if d.lower().endswith(white_list_formats):
      names.append(d)

print(f'Total number of valid images found: {len(names)}')
```

```
folders: ['Blight', 'Healthy', 'Common_Rust', 'Gray_Leaf_Spot']
Total number of valid images found: 4188
```

Split data by folders:

```
training_samples = 0
for p in paths:
  split = (0.2, 1)
  num_files = len(p)
  start, stop = int(split[0] * num_files), int(split[1] * num_files)
  valid_files = p[start: stop]
  training_samples += len(valid_files)
print(training_samples)


validation_samples = 0
for p in paths:
  split = (0, 0.2)
  num_files = len(p)
  start, stop = int(split[0] * num_files), int(split[1] * num_files)
  valid_files = p[start: stop]
  validation_samples += len(valid_files)
print(validation_samples)
```

```
3352
836
```

And this corresponds to what you see from `flow_from_directory`:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    width_shift_range = 0.05,
    height_shift_range = 0.05,
    rotation_range = 45,
    shear_range = 0.1,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    vertical_flip = True,
    validation_split = 0.2,
)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    validation_split = 0.2
)

train_images = datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/data',
    target_size=(150,150),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=42,
    subset='training',
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

val_images = val_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/data',
    target_size=(150,150), 
    batch_size=32, 
    seed=42,
    subset='validation', 
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode='categorical'
)
```

```
Found 3352 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 836 images belonging to 4 classes.
```

Note that I did not remove the 3 images like you did, but the logic remains the same.

Comment: Got it, I misinterpreted validation_split as a splitting all of the images combined, like how `train_test_split` splits dataframes, therefore I thought that there should be 0.2 * total images validation images, thanks for the explaination